# MVC posting form and extra param to an MVC controller using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to find a way to post a serialized form and an extra param to controller via ajax request. I can use `serialize()` on the form, or just send object with params, but cannot send both. How would I accomplish this?

For example I want my controller params to be as follows:

`myaction(int siteID, Model model).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pass what ever extra parameters you want along with form data as follows:**

```
 $.ajax({     type: 'POST',  
                 url: "/MyController/Process",
                 data: $("form").serialize() + '&id=12345' ,   
                 success: function () { alert("Successful"); },     
                 dataType: "json" 
    });
```

**Hope this helps..**

Comment: that is how it send? Man I feel like an idiot. I kept trying to convert it. Thanks man.

Comment: @Casey..You are welcome..Can you please mark as answer so that it might help some one in the future..

Comment: Yea, was making me wait a few minutes until it would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
var dataToPost = $('#formID').serialize() + "&siteID=" + "23";
```

Now use this `dataToPost` variable in jquery ajax method like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: //url,
            type: //'POST',
            dataType: //'html',
            async: true,
            data: dataToPost,
            cache: false,
        }).success(function (response, status, xhr) {

        }).fail(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
```